# How to create REST API of static page for WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-gutenberg

I have been trying to create REST API for WordPress to fetch data to my android application. I am using a plugin called wp rest API controller. But the problem is, I am creating a static page on my site. But I can't understand, How can I resolve this issue?

I have created below static page on my site and I want to saw the same page in my app.
and whenever I will change on this page then automatically change in the Mobile app through API.[This is static page that created on WordPress website][1]

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fN8E.png
```

Comment: In Wordpress you can use the Rest API to get the wordpress content to be shown on your "static" html page using javascript. Do I get your question the right way, you want to get data from an external and the content from that page should be displayed in your wordpress site? Don't really get the question, can you improve it? Thank you.

Comment: okay, I will check